# Need help solving ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Can I solve the given equation using Mathematica?

```
A = Log[a]; H = 1/a*D[a[t], t];
DSolve[{1/H*H'''[A] - 20*H  == 0}, H[A], A]
```

I am facing difficulties to solve this equation using Mathematica. Please, help me to solve this equation.

Comment: Could you write the problem in standard mathematical notation, too?  As it is, you've got `a` as a dependent variable and as an independent variable (`a[t]` and `a`  without the `[t]`, resp.); the same with `H` and `H[A]`; and `A` itself is not a variable but an expression `Log[a]`.  I can't figure out what you're trying to solve.

Comment: From where you got these equations? Any link?

Comment: Thank you so much Michael and zhk for your kind response. Actually this equation was using in my research work. This equation be written as                                            d^{3}H/dN^{3} = 7*H, where N = log(a) and H=(1/a)*(da/dt).

Comment: `DSolve[h'''[n] == 7 h[n], h, n]` gives the solution to $H'''[N] = 7 H[N]$ as a function of $N$.  (Avoid single capital letters since many are protected symbols with built-in meanings.) Does that get you what you want?

Comment: Bundles of thanks Michael. Yes, I have found the result.